# is a half closed interval a closed interval?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

So the complement of the set $(-1,1)$ is $(-\infty, -1] \cup [1, \infty)$ , however by defintion $(-\infty ,-1] \cup [1, \infty)$ is a half closed set, but by under defintion this same set is closed because it is the complement of $(-1,1)$, so is this set half closed or closed?

thanks!

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to format.

Comment: It is a closed set.

Comment: by defintion it is half closed no? since infinity is not included

Answer (score 0):

You are messing together two terms: closed intervals and closed sets. $(-\infty,-1]\cup[1,\infty)$ is a closed set but it consists of two half-closed intervals.

Answer (score 0):

There is AFAIK only a definition what a half-closed **interval** is (and even that is unclear when looking at infinite length intervals like $[1,\infty)$, for example). Asking if some set is half-closed doesn't make sense, IMO.

Finite length intervals are easily understandable examples of sets, so the nomenclature used for them has been extended to much more complicated sets. It just turns out that "half closed" is is not property that can be easily and usefully extended, because more complicated sets have a more complicated boundary.

A finite length interval has 2 boundary (or end) points, so the nomenclature is "open", "half-closed" and "closed" for containing 0, 1 or all 2 boundary points. Containing 0 or all boundary points generalizes neatly to "open" and "closed" concepts for general sets, but "cointaining a few but not all boundary points" turns out not to be a useful concept generally.